# AngularJS $location parameters mapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for AngularJS $location replacement which allows me to map url parameters more flexible.

For example, I have two root pages `map` and `blog` and some parameters for map page. Now how it looks like in angular:

```
example.com/#!/map?id=1234567&view=12,43.5,55.5
```

I want to throw away `?` and `&` garbage and get url like this

```
example.com/#!/map/1234567/view/12/43.5/55.5

example.com/#!/map/1234567 
view is an optional parameter

example.com/#!/map/1234567/details
details is an optional flag
```

But I still want to use `$location.search(view, '12,43.5,55.5')` or `$location.search(id, '1234567')` or something similar.

Is it possible to change Angular `$location` to get such behavior or is there any usable alternatives?

Comment: Can't you achieve this behavior by using angularjs' routing?

Comment: I don't think so, ofc. I can set `/map/1234567/view/12/43.5/55.5` as a page, but it's very uncomfortable to read parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [angular ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) or you use the default angularjs' routing like [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example):

```
.when('/map/:id', {}
.when('/map/:id/details', {}
.when('/map/:mapId/view/:id*', {}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

- path can contain named groups starting with a colon and ending with a
  star: e.g.:name*. All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams
  under the given name when the route matches.

For example, routes like `/color/:color/largecode/:largecode*\/edit` will match `/color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashes/edit` and extract:

Comment: Looks like something what I need. Thank you Betty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $state.go() instead of $location.
$state.go('pagename');

Comment: But in this case I should read and write parameters from and into pagename string by myself, and I'm looking for better way.